# Appcelerator. Handle memory usage. Best practice

Tags: memory-leaks, appcelerator-mobile

Titanium SDK version: 1.7.0 
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am developing an iOS app and I monitor the memory usage for each window And it keeps decreasing for every screen.

1. What is consuming memory in general? I use views, tables and XHR data.
2. How can I release memory / decrease usage on each window?

Thankful for all input!

Comment: I wish I had an answer for you. Struggling with this in apps that are using a few images.

Very interested to know what other devs are doing to avoid their apps up and quitting. I'm getting sick of seeing: "OutOfMemory, VM failed on a <x> byte allocation."

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are dealing with JavaScript being translated to Objective-C and can't necessarily write a native solution without using modules you could start by setting window variables to `null` *(`myJsWindowVar = null;`)*, or delete those variables using `delete` *(`delete myJsWindowVar;`)*. Personally I think setting variables to `null` will better translate to the suggested Objective-C best practice which is to set a pointer reference to `null` and prevent orphaned objects from hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close unused windows and clear our any references to native objects you no longer need in the app.

```
// create a window object
var aWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var aLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({ text : "Hey" });
aWindow.add(aLabel);
aWindow.open();

// done with window
aWindow.close();
aWindow = null;
aLabel.null;
```

Check out [this presentation](http://bit.ly/pOl6tj) from the Appcelerator Codestrong conference for more details.